# What are the available audit plugins for MySQL 8.0 Community Edition RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, audit

I have an AWS RDS MySQL 8.0 Community Edition DB. I need to enable audit in MySQL 8.0 (RDS). When I read the AWS documentation I found there is maria DB audit plugin for MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 later versions.
I checked the option groups of my db (mysql 8.0) but I couldn't find maria db audit plugin option, but for 5.6 and 5.7 its available.
Am I missing something here or are there any other audit plugins that can be used with MySQL 8.0 RDS instance ?

Comment: I confirm that as of today, the AWS RDS MySQL 8.0 Community Edition option group does not include MariaDB Audit Plugin.

Comment: As a workaround for auditing RDS MySQL 8, you can use the solution based on a proxy like DataSunrise

Answer (score 1):

When a new RDS MySQL machine is launched, it has default Option and Parameter groups. If you need to enable MariaDB Audit Plugin, you need to create a new Option group and modify the same to enable MariaDB_Audit_Plugin and further set other options available under this plugin.

Once the New option group is all set, attach the same to the RDS MySQL machine, then apply changes immediately.

Also you can refer to the AWS Documentation below:

https://apg-library.amazonaws.com/content/bb362793-85b6-4fac-98dc-a99b558934ab
-- Iam not sure if you have access to the above Pattern as the same is yet to move to the public domain.

Having said that below document is over public and can guide you for your use case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.Options.AuditPlugin.html